# I have always to re-enter the Exchange credentials when I start Outlook

Tags: outlook, credentials

Each time I start Outlook I have to enter the Exchange credentials for each account I have defined in the profile. Due to the fact the profile has 5 accounts it becomes a bit tiresome.

This Outlook is running on a LAN which is connected to the Exchange via VPN and it is on another subnet.

The Outlook running inside a Terminal Server session works fine and doesn't ask for the credentials even that profile has more accounts defined.

Of course, I check the option for save the credentials. I deleted already the profile and re-entered all accounts. When I was asked there to enter the credentials so I checked the option to save the data.

As long Outlook is open I am not asked anymore and everything works finr - so it is not similar to this [question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/718770/active-directory-credentials-issue-constantly-asking-to-re-enter-rejection).

**What can it be and how do I get rid of it?**

---

- Exchange 2010
- SBS 2011 Standard
- Outlook 2013

---

This is the dialog I see each time I start Outlook. Some parts are in German.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/969278/277875) from [Beverly Gao](https://serverfault.com/users/522447/beverly-gao) put me in the right direction.

The problem was that I didn't add the domain to the username when I connected the first time to the Exchange Server. Therefore there was only one entry in the Credential Manager with the **last** username/password I entered.

This means, when I entered the credentials for `USER1` Windows updated the entry for `USER1`. Then, due to the fact I have 5 accounts in the profile, I was asked for the password of `USER2`, `USER3`, `USER4` and `USER5`. Each time I entered the credentials for one user Windows overwrote now the entry for the *previously* entered user - and so on.

The below screenshot shows what I mean. Before I started to add the domain there was **only the last entry** `AAEB-SBS201WX...` which is my Exchange. So, Outlook never had a chance to get the correct credentials for the 5 accounts because the Credential Manager had only one entry - for the last entered user/account.

Now, as you can see in the screenshot each account is saved with the domain and username and it works finally. You see in the screenshot the `\` which is separating the domain and username.

I kept for the screenshot the last entry. Now it doesn't exist - only the entries with the `DOMAIN\UserName` format.

**I was not aware of the need to provide the domain because inside the Windows Terminal Server it isn't needed**. As I wrote, I am connecting via VPN to the SBS which is in another subnet.

[image]

---

PS: Please feel free to correct my English.

Answer (score 1):

Having met the same issue with you, then I took the suggestions in [How to get rid of the password prompt every time you open Outlook](https://www.it-support.com.au/how-to-get-rid-of-the-password-prompt-every-time-you-open-outlook/2018/02/) it works.
However, there are a lot of causes for this issue. If you click cancel, do Outlook change to Disconnected, goes into Need Password state or remains Connected? 
Similar issue for your reference https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/116fa7cd-82f8-447c-b3f1-db2cbf0c6b66/outlook-anywhere-prompts-for-password-in-outlook?forum=Exch2016SD

Comment: Read my answer. +1 because you put me into the right direction. Anyway, it was still a pain and playing around for 2 hours until I realized what is going on!

Comment: It's glad to hear that your problem has been solved, thanks for your sharing.